# Visual Studio 2019 - C# - Windows Forms App - Background Image - resources.resx shows 'none' - why are my images not shown?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 - C# - Windows Forms App .Net Core

Visual Studio newby question..

I have added images that are shown in resources.resc and listed under Resources as shown below:

[image]

I have then gone into Form1.cs properties - BackgroundImage

[image]

Why does it say (none) under Project resource file resources.resx - why are my images not shown?

Comment: Use File > Save All to ensure the changes you made to the resources are saved and visible to the designer.

Comment: Your images are not part of the Resources.resx file. You'll also need to set the Build Action of the images to "Resource".

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried both of those things and they are still not shown.

Comment: Also if I go into the form properties, choose Background Image and import, the images are imported but the background image still says none.

Comment: @Matt Hi matt, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this must have been a bug in Visual Studio.

I have upgraded to Visual Studio 22 and it is working fine now.